# How to upgrade Linux Kernel (Linux vps180 2.6.32-37-pve #1 SMP Wed Mar 18 08:19:56 CET 2015 i686 GNU/Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel, proxmox

Good Day!

Im having a difficulties in upgrading this server's kernel. Since I am new to this server management. Anyone who have idea to upgrade this type of server ?

**Linux vps180 2.6.32-37-pve #1 SMP Wed Mar 18 08:19:56 CET 2015 i686**.

I try also to use **apt-get dist-upgrade** but here are the results.

**Reading package lists... Done**

**Building dependency tree**
**Reading state information... Done**

**Calculating upgrade... Done**

**0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.**\

Any help will much really appreciated.

Comment: Is `apt-get dist-upgrade` the only thing you tried?

Comment: Which version of debian is this?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update the apt repository info first**

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That should do a full distribution update on Debian based systems and you'll have the latest kernel for that release.

**Troubleshooting**

If that doesn't seem to work, things in /etc/apt could be broken - such as missing or misconfigured repositories.

See `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Read `man sources.list` and google `sources.list` examples for your distribution.